# Mathematically expressing the sum of odd and even numbers

Tags: soft-question

I am aware that if I want to write the product of a function $2N^2$ starting with numbers from $1$ to $n$, I write something like this $\prod_{N=1}^{n} 2N^2$, what if I want $N$ to start from 1 and step through odd numbers or even numbers? How do I express this? It is a simple question but I am getting somethings a bit mixed up.

Comment: That product notation doesn't even make sense. Your question in general is also rather unclear. An explicit example would help a lot...

Comment: $\prod_{k=0}^N 2(2k+1)^2$

Comment: Its been edited. Thanks

Comment: @Zachary Hunter, I guess that is meant for the even function. Cant one use the $\prod$ sign?

Comment: You’re overloading the N variable

Comment: Yes. I hope this helps. Also, you notation is still ill defined as you have N as both a variable and a constant.

Comment: Your title refers to a sum while the body refers to a product.  The question is the same, but they should be consistent.  When you write $\prod_{N=1}^{N} 2N^2$ you are using $N$ in two different ways.  The top one is the upper limit of the dummy variable while the other two are the dummy variable.  It would be *much* better to write $\prod_{N=1}^{n} 2N^2$  The result will depend on $n$ but not $N$.

Comment: Thanks @Ross Millikan, I edited the question, I want to retain the product sign and express the product of $2N^2$ taking $N$ in steps of 2 for odd and even numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to step through the even numbers, you can write $\prod _{n=1}^k(2(2n)^2)$.  If you want to step through the odd numbers, you can write $\prod _{n=0}^k(2(2n+1)^2)$.  I don't know of a mathematical equivalent to the computer step as in for i=1 to 11 step 2 other than this.

I have seen the notation $$\sum_{\stackrel {p \le n}{p \text { prime}}}$$ for the sum of some expression over all the primes less than or equal to $n$.

Using the formula for even numbers makes it easier to deal with.  In your example we can recognize the factorial and write 
$$\prod _{n=1}^k(2(2n)^2)=2^k(k!)^2\\
\prod _{n=0}^k(2(2n+1)^2)=2^{k+1}\left(\frac {(2n+1)!}{2^nn!}\right)^2$$

Comment: @Thanks Ross!, but with the square you have just included, I guess it would not start from 1 and 2 this time.

Comment: We can just start with $n=0$ or use $2n-1$ if you want to start from $1$.  I'll fix.  You need to check the limits each time to make sure you get what you want and no more.  The even one does start with $2$.

Comment: I want to start with 1, I guess it looks like $\prod _{n=1}^k(2(2n-1)^2)$ and for the even $\prod _{n=1}^k((2n))$

Comment: I would think, as in my answer, that for the evens you want $2(2n)^2$ because you said you wanted the product of $2N^2$ for $N$ even.  $2n$ will just give you the product of all the even numbers.  That is fine if that is what you want.  $2n$ starts $2,4,6,8$ while $2(2n)^2 starts $8,32,72$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Ross Milikan